# Showing a man page in C++

Tags: c++, manpage

I created a man page for my C++ application and I would like to show it to the user when a particular flag is specified in the command line. Is `system("man myapplication")` the only way to do this, or are there any better options?

Comment: Do you want to continue after displaying the man page?

Comment: @KerrekSB no, just return a value from `main`.

Comment: In that case you could do `execl("/usr/bin/man", "/usr/bin/man", "myapplication", NULL)`, but as msw says, that requires all the dependencies to be met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably take the nroff (text) output of `man` and stick it either in the code as one huge string or in a separate file depending on how many pieces the program installs with.

Calling `system("man")` requires a lot of dependencies which is the last thing your unfortunate user wants to deal with after typing `my_program --long-help`. It would work just fine in many cases, but when it didn't you'd lose an important feature of your program and have to report the rather silly "sorry: no long help available".

This would also increase portability to systems that never had a `man` program.